# Images captured using CameraX are larger compared to images captured using Camera1

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

We are working on updating our legacy Camera application to use CameraX APIs instead of Camera1 APIs. We have used same camera configurations in both Camera1 and CameraX, we read the JPEG image byte array from Camera, in-memory and then upload that to a server. However, we have noticed that the byte array length that is got from CameraX is around 2X that of the byte array that we get from Camera1. Does CameraX output has some additional data or metadata in the byte array that is got in the callback? Or, are we doing something wrong while reading byte array from ImageProxy?

Camera Initialization in Camera1 along with setting target resolution, JPEG quality:

```
camera = Camera.open(cameraId); //cameraId is the ID of back camera
parameters = camera.getParameters();

//set target resolution to 1600 * 1200
parameters.setPictureSize(1600, 1200);

//set JPEG quality to 100
parameters.setJpegQuality(100);

//set image format to JPEG
setImageFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
```

Camera Initliazation in CameraX along with setting target resolution, JPEG quality:

```
//select back camera
CameraSelector cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA;

//create preview
Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();

//create Image Capture use case, set JPEG quality to 100, target resolution to 1600*1200
ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setJpegQuality(100)
        .setTargetResolution(new Size(1600, 1200))
        .build();

//by default output format will be JPEG, no need to explicitly set it.

//start camera 
provider.bindToLifecycle(
        this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture
);
```

Callback method passed to takePicture method in Camera API:

```
camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, pictureTaken);

private Camera.PictureCallback pictureTaken = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
   @Override
   public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera){
         Log.d(“Data byte array length”, data.length); // for same image this is around 400000 bytes


       ///Logic to upload data to server    
   }
```

Callback method passed to takePicture method in CameraX API:

```
imageCapture.takePicture(ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this), 
    new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy imageProxy) {
            //convert imageProxy to byte array, image format is JPEG.
            ByteBuffer buffer = imageProxy.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            buffer.rewind();
            byte[] data = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(data);

            
            Log.d(“Data byte array length”, data.length); //for same image this is around 700000 bytes
        }
    
)
```

Final image size is also considerably higher in CameraX implementation. In Camera its around 400kb and in CameraX its around 700kb. Is there any configuration we are missing or is there any metadata in the byte array that we need to strip off ?

Comment: But what exactly is in those byte arrays? And you start with telling you upload a raw image to the server but then all the code is commented with jpeg.

Comment: Byte array should be having image data and Exif metadata. In the commented code we just convert the byte array to ByteArrayOutputStream and make a multi-part form request to server, passing the ByteArrayOutputStream.

Comment: `having image data` Very unclear! Raw? Jpeg? Or what? Be exact! You ask for reasons why the arrays are not equal in size. What do they contain? How can we give an answer if all is vague!?

Comment: Byte array contains JPEG data. Sorry, i wasn't clear. We read the data as got from camera, thats what I had meant by raw.

Comment: Raw is something different as you should know. So it contains the bytes of a .jpg file. Do both files have the same resolution?

Comment: Yes, both files have same resolution.

Comment: This is interesting. 2 questions: which devices did you use? If you capture a picture with camera2basic, what is the size? https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Basic

Comment: Used Pixel 4 and Pixel 6a. Camer2Basic sample app also produces image with larger  size as compared to Camera1.